# How could I centralise AngularJS configuration when part of an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AngularJS SPA served up as part of an ASP.NET MVC application. Within this I have an Angular factory which accesses a REST API elsewhere on our intranet. We have various instances of this API for development, production and UAT. I'd like to be able to configure the URL of this API within something like the web.config so that when I build each different solution configuration the correct URL is provided to the factory.

Unfortunately I'm working within an environment where I cannot use npm (it's complicated - suffice it to say that NTLM proxy authentication combined with a smartcard login don't play nicely with npm), so a lot of front-end build tools that seem like they might have been helpful aren't available to use.

Currently I'm just thinking of adding a method on a controller which returns a value in the web.config, but this doesn't seem terribly elegant. Perhaps there's a better way?

Comment: I create an MVC controller action that returns the values I need as an angular constant. Details here... http://anthonychu.ca/post/how-to-pass-webconfig-settings-to-angularjs

Comment: That's pretty much the kind of solution I was thinking about. It's good to know I'm not the only one to consider it! :)